# Desktop PC won't boot after power outage

Tags: windows, boot, hardware-failure

My desktop PC won't boot into windows (stock after POST) after power outage although I am not working on the PC when this happens and it happens each time a power outage occurs.

When I run windows recovery, the problem always seems to be that the C drive containing the windows partition is corrupt, sometimes it can be fixed and other times I need to format.

I wonder why this happens all the time, the PC I had before this one and which I used for almost seven years never had this issue even if a power outage occurs while I am working.

Comment: Use a surge protector. Also, why are you getting so many power outages?

Comment: Also, the idea that "Desktop won't boot after each power outage" makes no sense. It either doesn't boot at all after 1 power outage, or it doesn't boot for a while after each power outage.

Comment: @Wutnaut I mean each time I fix the problem (either by running chkdsk utitlity or formatting) and a power outage happens again, the problem comes back.

Comment: @Wutnaut I thought surge protectors help with voltage irregularities, but I think this isn't my cause here.

Comment: but you cant run chkdsk or format if it doesn't boot, which you're saying happens after a power outage. Please clarify.

Comment: @Wutnaut I run chkdsk and format from the Windows DVD.